# How to achieve a generic format for date column in Informatica from source having different format of date for date column

Tags: oracle, informatica

Period is a column coming from source which has dates in 3 different formats. I need to convert these to one single format that is 'MON-YY' and dump it into target table.

Source table :

```
Period 
-------------------
JUN-17
JUN-2017
JUN-06-2017
```

Target table:

```
Period 
-------------------
JUN-17
JUN-17
JUN-17
```

Comment: Why are you storing dates - even nominal dates representing a period - as strings?

Comment: Yes,  that's how the data is..

Comment: I tried using regex_replace to achieve it but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure you only have strings in those three formats you can just use [the `substr()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SUBSTR.html) twice to get the start and end sections, and concatenate them back together:

```
select substr(period, 1, 4) || substr(period, -2)
from source_table
```

Demo with those values in a CTE:

```
with source_table(period) as (
            select 'JUN-17' from dual
  union all select 'JUN-2017' from dual
  union all select 'JUN-06-2017' from dual
)
select substr(period, 1, 4) || substr(period, -2)
from source_table;

SUBSTR
------
JUN-17
JUN-17
JUN-17
```